# self is immutable

Tags: macos, swift2

I have a class, Task, with a 'count' property. The end goal is to increase the count by 1.

In a playground, this is working:

```
class Task: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var count: Int

    init(name:String, count:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.count = count
    }
}

var test = Task(name: "test", count: 0)

test.count += 1

// => 1
```

But in my actual project, it's getting this error:

> Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'self' is immutable

In my ViewController, I have an @IBAction function that I'd like to trigger the count increase, so that's where the error is occurring. Here's a trimmed down version:

```
@IBAction func addTask(sender: AnyObject) {
    currentTask = newTaskInput.stringValue

    let x = Task(name: currentTask, count: 0)
    currentTaskObj = x

    // error occurs here
    currentTaskObj!.count += 1
}
```

Any idea how to fix this? I must be missing something because it's working in a playground exactly how I'd like. Huge thanks in advance!

**Edit:** here's the actual class from my project (I changed sessions to count for the examples above):

```
class Task: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String
    var sessions: Int
    var time: String = ""

    init(name:String, sessions:Int, time:String? = "") {
        self.name = name
        self.sessions = sessions
        self.time = time!
    }

    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        var name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        var sessions = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("sessions") as! Int
        var time = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("time") as! String
        self.init(name: name, sessions: sessions, time: time)
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.sessions, forKey: "sessions")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.time, forKey: "time")
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `currentTaskObj`?

Comment: Oh sorry. I am just trying to keep track of things - i have the variables `currentTask` and `currentTaskObj` set up outside of the function. I'd like to set up the currentTaskObj to be the object I'm working with.

Comment: The definition of the `Task` class and the way it's being used in the other snippet do not match up. `init` does not produce an optional, and that error message doesn't apply to classes. You need to include the definition that's actually in your project.

Comment: @JoshCaswell the '!' was a suggestion from xcode, it doesn't seem to make any difference if I take it off though. I'm definitely new to optionals and unwrapping. I added the whole class to the OP.

Comment: If I skip assigning the value of `x` to `currentTaskObj` and instead update the sessions for `x` - it works. Apparently it doesn't like being assigned to another variable first. Any idea why? I got it working but would like to understand how.